# Add Array elements to ComboBox

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to add items from an array to my ComboBox.

I have an array, "materialArray" that I search for unique items with the `in_array()` function then I add them to a new array, "uniqueMateral", that I then try to add to "ComboBox2".

I receive:

> "Run-time Error '70': Permission denied".

on the line: `ActiveSheet.ComboBox2.AddItem (uniqueMaterial(i))`

My code and the two functions I use in the code: `in_array()` and `Is_Var_Array_Empty()`.

```vb
Sub ComboBox2_DropButtonClick()

Dim lastRowMaterial As Long
Dim uniqueMaterial() As Variant
Dim materialArray() As Variant

lastRowMaterial = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row         'Gets Length of column H (Material)
    materialArray = Sheet1.Range("Data!H4:H" & lastRowMaterial)       'Gets whole material list into Array
    ReDim uniqueMaterial(0)
    
    If Is_Var_Array_Empty(uniqueMaterial) Then
        uniqueMaterial(0) = materialArray(1, 1)
    End If
    
    For i = LBound(materialArray) To UBound(materialArray)
        If Not in_array(uniqueMaterial, materialArray(i, 1)) Then
            ReDim Preserve uniqueMaterial(UBound(uniqueMaterial) + 1)
            uniqueMaterial(UBound(uniqueMaterial)) = materialArray(i, 1)
        End If
    Next
    
    For i = LBound(uniqueMaterial) To UBound(uniqueMaterial)
        ActiveSheet.ComboBox2.AddItem uniqueMaterial(i)
                        'Copies unique materials to dropdown list
    Next
                                                
End Sub
```

```
Function Is_Var_Array_Empty(arr_var As Variant)     'Function to check wether array is empty or not
 
Dim p As Integer
 
On Error Resume Next
    p = UBound(arr_var, 1)
If Err.Number = 0 Then
    Is_Var_Array_Empty = False
Else
    Is_Var_Array_Empty = True
End If
 
End Function
```

```
Function in_array(my_array, my_value)
    
    in_array = False
    
    For i = LBound(my_array) To UBound(my_array)
        If my_array(i) = my_value Then 'If value found
            in_array = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: `ActiveSheet.ComboBox2.AddItem (uniqueMaterial(i))` Parentheses are not required here and can cause unexpected errors. not sure if linked to the error you have or not.

Comment: Thank you for the information Vincent G , I removed the parentheses but the error still shows up at the same place.

Comment: The `+ 1` in `For i = LBound(uniqueMaterial) + 1 To UBound(uniqueMaterial)` might cause issues if there is only one entry in `uniqueMaterial` - are you sure that's what you want?

Comment: Thank you CLR, the + 1 was mostly a quick fix to an earlier problem. I removed it but the error still exists.